# ASP.NET Core 3 - immediately instantiate a singleton after services.AddSingelton<IMySingletone, MySingletone>();

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton, asp.net-core-3.0

How to immediately instantiate a singleton after

```
services.AddSingelton<IMySingleton, MySingleton>()
```

I'm using this dirty workaround for now (call `GetService` in every request):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IFirebaseApp_ForInjection>();

    //......
}
```

I know my singleton should be instantiated when needed in constructor injection, but I don't need to inject it into any constructor.

Comment: Does your singleton require dependencies? There is nothing stopping you from instantiating the implementation before adding it to the services collection as a singleton.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the target singleton has no explicitly injected dependencies, there is nothing stopping it from being instantiated before adding it to the services collection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //...

    IMySingleton instance = new MySingleton();
    services.AddSingelton(instance)

    //...
}
```

If there are dependencies, then another option would be similar to the currently shown workaround by injecting it into `Configure` method in startup

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IMySingleton instance) {
    //...
}
```

That way any registered dependencies will be resolved and injected.

Comment: My singleton needs IWebHostEnvironment dependency

Comment: Then in that case the second suggested option would be the way to go. That way the dependency will be injected.